# should i always use useEffect when working with localStorage in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

iam developing an app which stores data in localStorage. when the app first renders, i want to load all data stored in localStorage . But what haappens with useEffect is, it only runs after the app renders for the first time and then it loads the data from localStorage.

So iam not able to use the data for anything that happen at the time of rendering such as displaying the data !!

Comment: I think you have to paste some code snippets for better understanding.

Comment: Then use `useLayoutEffect` if you need to perform work prior to rendering

Comment: iam thinking about it, but can anyone  answer this : is it necessary to use useEffect  whenever dealing with localStorage ?

Comment: What do you mean by if it is necessary? You need to read from local storage anyway during the lifecycle of a component, so you will need to use `useEffect` or the likes of it.

Comment: but it's working fine without useEffect. that is why iam asking

Comment: When? Application initialization or component mount?